# Gnome overview laggy when running scaling_governor=powersave

Tags: gnome, power-management, performance, cpu

I have a Dell XPS 13 9370 with an i7-8550u CPU which should handle Gnome without any issues. The Ubuntu version is 18.04. But now experience the following problem:
When setting the scaling governor to powersave the activity overview animation is very laggy (that one you access by pressing the Super key only). Furthermore it feels a bit strange for me that my system idles with a CPU frequency of 800 MHz but the CPU specification says that the base frequency is 1.8 GHz.
If I set the governor to performance those animations are absolutely smooth. The problem is that the CPU now idles at around 3 GHz which results in a high battery consumption.

So what's exactly my question: Is it normal that exactly that Gnome animation is laggy? If so, can we expect an improvement in upcoming versions? Are the configurations with the intel_pstate driver correct? Why is the CPU not able to increase the frequency fast enough to make this animation smooth? Could I maybe disable this specific animation? Is it normal that my CPU idles with a lower frequency than its description says?

Best regards

Comment: Are you *only* changing the scaling governor, or do you mean this happens when switching between on and off battery? That's quite a different thing: TLP does a lot more than just CPU scaling (it may e.g. twiddle with your GPU). Please edit your question to clarify exactly what you did, with commands and their outputs. Also please condense your list of questions into a single one, and post different questions as new questions.

Comment: It is only happening when changing the governor.
echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor and everything is fine.
echo powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor and the animation is laggy.

I'll take the tlp mention out of the original post because it is confusing and does not help.

Comment: The reason I'd put this bunch of questions because I would like to understand the whole problem and mention some ideas to probably solve it.

Comment: Using scaling you can set your minimum to say 1600 MHz as a short term fix. Also make sure turbo boost is on. Install TLP.

Comment: Also as 8500 is so new check for kernel bugs and if known apply latest mainline.

Comment: Suggest to try [kernel 4.18](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.18/), just as a test. It is normal, indeed expected, for your processor to idle down to 800 MHz. While performance mode ramps up CPU frequency extremely fast, it doesn't necessarily mean it consumes a lot more power, because it also spends more time in idle because it got the job done faster. The cpu should be able to ramp up frequency fast enough for smooth video.

Comment: tlp is installed and I tried the newest 4.18.1 kernel but it didn't help.
The problem with performance mode or a higher base frequency is that I loose 20-50% battery life which kind of hurts.
What I found in `dmesg` is the following
`[   10.307709] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_GPE.XTBT.SPRT], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180531/dswload2-316)`
Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like I have found the problem.

I wrote a little script which measured the CPU frequency every 1/10 second and the result was that the CPU wasn't correctly scaling up when pressing the Super button to get the gnome overview (it did not exceed 2200 MHz). 
After removing tlp the CPU scales up to round 300MHz (and that much faster!) which results in a non-laggy overview.

So it seems like that tlp cuts off the CPU frequency.